# How to check PHP file syntax from the code?

Tags: php, html, web, exception, include

I'am `include` some files of my website by `mvc.php`.
And I want that if there are errors in PHP code - user see my error page instead of exceptions.

I tried to catch errors with `try/catch`, but include errors skips it

```
try {
    include '../index.php';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    include 'errors/error501.php';
}
return;
```

With ths code there is just an exception text of my corrupted file:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '/', expecting end of file in W:\domains\amelia.lc\dev\index.php on line 87
```

I tried to check file with `php_check_syntax`, but this function were deleted from PHP

How can i solve it?

Comment: Include(‘filetoinclude.php’)

Comment: Lelio Faieta, nothing changed

Comment: Not sure of the exact scenario that leads to PHP files being changed and deployed to production without being even run but [overtrue /
phplint](https://github.com/overtrue/phplint) is a lovely command-line utility for batch linting.

Comment: Álvaro González, how i gonna use command line on the hosting?

Comment: You can use PuTTY, `system()`, `exec()`... or check code locally before deploying since the language syntax is the same in your local PC and in your internet host. But, as I said, I don't know the details of your scenario. Why do those PHP source code files appear randomly in your server? Are they uploaded by users?